# Why does my "T" have a gap in it?

Tags: fonts

I'm trying to use the Calligra package to make a nice "The End" page for my book. However, the T has a big gap in it and I have no idea why. Here's a slimmed down example showing the issue:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %note: happens with or without this line

\begin{document}

\calligra{The End}

\end{document}
```

Which ends up looking like this:

[image: T has a gap in it]

Judging from [this reference](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/calligra/) the T should be connected, without the white square missing and look like this:

[image: Working T]

I am using Texmaker with MiKTeX on Windows 10, here's the log output from my build:

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.10) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.10.25) 8 NOV 2020 12:21
entering extended mode
**./t_problem.tex
(t_problem.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2020-10-05> xparse <2020-03-03>
(C:\Users\Julian\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/memoir\memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2020/10/04 v3.7n configurable book, report, article docu
ment class
\onelineskip=\skip47
\lxvchars=\skip48
\xlvchars=\skip49
\@memcnta=\count175
\c@@memmarkcntra=\count176
(C:\Users\Julian\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)
\stockheight=\skip50
\stockwidth=\skip51
\trimtop=\skip52
\trimedge=\skip53
(C:\Users\Julian\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/memoir\mem10.clo
File: mem10.clo 2008/01/30 v0.3 memoir class 10pt size option
)
\binding=\skip54
\spinemargin=\skip55
\foremargin=\skip56
\uppermargin=\skip57
\lowermargin=\skip58
\headdrop=\skip59
\normalrulethickness=\skip60
\mem@maxheadheight=\skip61
\mem@maxfootheight=\skip62
\headwidth=\skip63
\c@storedpagenumber=\count177
\memPD=\dimen138
\m@mabparskip=\skip64
\thanksmarkwidth=\skip65
\thanksmarksep=\skip66
\droptitle=\skip67
\c@book=\count178
\c@part=\count179
\c@chapter=\count180
\c@section=\count181
\c@subsection=\count182
\c@subsubsection=\count183
\c@paragraph=\count184
\c@subparagraph=\count185
\beforechapskip=\skip68
\midchapskip=\skip69
\afterchapskip=\skip70
\chapindent=\skip71
\bottomsectionskip=\skip72
\secindent=\skip73
\beforesecskip=\skip74
\aftersecskip=\skip75
\subsecindent=\skip76
\beforesubsecskip=\skip77
\aftersubsecskip=\skip78
\subsubsecindent=\skip79
\beforesubsubsecskip=\skip80
\aftersubsubsecskip=\skip81
\paraindent=\skip82
\beforeparaskip=\skip83
\afterparaskip=\skip84
\subparaindent=\skip85
\beforesubparaskip=\skip86
\aftersubparaskip=\skip87
\pfbreakskip=\skip88
\c@@ppsavesec=\count186
\c@@ppsaveapp=\count187
\ragrparindent=\dimen139
\everylistparindent=\dimen140
\parsepi=\skip89
\topsepi=\skip90
\itemsepi=\skip91
\parsepii=\skip92
\topsepii=\skip93
\topsepiii=\skip94
\itemsepii=\skip95
\itemsepiii=\skip96
\partopsepii=\skip97
\partopsepiii=\skip98
\m@msavetopsep=\skip99
\m@msavepartopsep=\skip100
\@enLab=\toks15
\abstitleskip=\skip101
\absleftindent=\skip102
\abs@leftindent=\dimen141
\absrightindent=\skip103
\absparindent=\skip104
\absparsep=\skip105
\c@vslineno=\count188
\c@poemline=\count189
\c@modulo@vs=\count190
\c@memfvsline=\count191
\vleftskip=\skip106
\vrightskip=\skip107
\stanzaskip=\skip108
\versewidth=\skip109
\vgap=\skip110
\vindent=\skip111
\vleftmargin=\dimen142
\c@verse=\count192
\c@chrsinstr=\count193
\beforepoemtitleskip=\skip112
\afterpoemtitleskip=\skip113
\c@poem=\count194
\beforePoemTitleskip=\skip114
\midPoemTitleskip=\skip115
\afterPoemTitleskip=\skip116
(C:\Users\Julian\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\array.sty
Package: array 2019/08/31 v2.4l Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen143
\ar@mcellbox=\box47
\extrarowheight=\dimen144
\NC@list=\toks16
\extratabsurround=\skip117
\backup@length=\skip118
\ar@cellbox=\box48
)
(C:\Users\Julian\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\dcolumn.sty
Package: dcolumn 2014/10/28 v1.06 decimal alignment package (DPC)
)
(C:\Users\Julian\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\delarray.sty
Package: delarray 2014/10/28 v1.01 array delimiter package (DPC)
)
(C:\Users\Julian\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\tabularx.sty
Package: tabularx 2020/01/15 v2.11c `tabularx' package (DPC)
\TX@col@width=\dimen145
\TX@old@table=\dimen146
\TX@old@col=\dimen147
\TX@target=\dimen148
\TX@delta=\dimen149
\TX@cols=\count195
\TX@ftn=\toks17
)
\heavyrulewidth=\dimen150
\lightrulewidth=\dimen151
\cmidrulewidth=\dimen152
\belowrulesep=\dimen153
\belowbottomsep=\dimen154
\aboverulesep=\dimen155
\abovetopsep=\dimen156
\cmidrulesep=\dimen157
\cmidrulekern=\dimen158
\defaultaddspace=\dimen159
\@cmidla=\count196
\@cmidlb=\count197
\@aboverulesep=\dimen160
\@belowrulesep=\dimen161
\@thisruleclass=\count198
\@lastruleclass=\count199
\@thisrulewidth=\dimen162
\ctableftskip=\skip119
\ctabrightskip=\skip120
\abovecolumnspenalty=\count266
\@linestogo=\count267
\@cellstogo=\count268
\@cellsincolumn=\count269
\crtok=\toks18
\@mincolumnwidth=\dimen163
\c@newflo@tctr=\count270
\mem@margin@floatbox=\box49
\@contcwidth=\skip121
\@contindw=\skip122
\abovecaptionskip=\skip123
\belowcaptionskip=\skip124
\subfloattopskip=\skip125
\subfloatcapskip=\skip126
\subfloatcaptopadj=\skip127
\subfloatbottomskip=\skip128
\subfloatlabelskip=\skip129
\subfloatcapmargin=\dimen164
\c@@contsubnum=\count271
\m@mscap@capbox=\box50
\m@mscap@fbox=\box51
\sidecapsep=\dimen165
\sidecapwidth=\dimen166
\m@m@tempdima=\dimen167
\m@mscapraise=\dimen168
\sidecapraise=\dimen169
\m@mscapmainwidth=\dimen170
\m@mscaplkern=\dimen171
\beforeepigraphskip=\skip130
\afterepigraphskip=\skip131
\epigraphwidth=\skip132
\epigraphrule=\skip133
LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 7678.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \emph on input line 7686.
\tocentryskip=\skip134
\tocbaseline=\skip135
\cftparskip=\skip136
\cftbeforebookskip=\skip137
\cftbookindent=\dimen172
\cftbooknumwidth=\dimen173
\cftbeforepartskip=\skip138
\cftpartindent=\skip139
\cftpartnumwidth=\skip140
\cftbeforechapterskip=\skip141
\cftchapterindent=\skip142
\cftchapternumwidth=\skip143
\cftbeforesectionskip=\skip144
\cftsectionindent=\skip145
\cftsectionnumwidth=\skip146
\cftbeforesubsectionskip=\skip147
\cftsubsectionindent=\skip148
\cftsubsectionnumwidth=\skip149
\cftbeforesubsubsectionskip=\skip150
\cftsubsubsectionindent=\skip151
\cftsubsubsectionnumwidth=\skip152
\cftbeforeparagraphskip=\skip153
\cftparagraphindent=\skip154
\cftparagraphnumwidth=\skip155
\cftbeforesubparagraphskip=\skip156
\cftsubparagraphindent=\skip157
\cftsubparagraphnumwidth=\skip158
\prechapterprecisshift=\dimen174
\c@maxsecnumdepth=\count272
\bibindent=\dimen175
\bibitemsep=\skip159
\indexcolsep=\skip160
\indexrule=\skip161
\indexmarkstyle=\toks19
\@indexbox=\insert252
\glossarycolsep=\dimen176
\glossaryrule=\dimen177
\sideparvshift=\skip162
\sideins=\insert251
\sidebartopsep=\skip163
\sidebarhsep=\skip164
\sidebarvsep=\skip165
\sidebarwidth=\skip166
\footmarkwidth=\skip167
\footmarksep=\skip168
\footparindent=\skip169
\footinsdim=\skip170
\footinsv@r=\insert250
\@mpfootinsv@r=\insert249
\m@m@k=\count273
\m@m@h=\dimen178
\m@mipn@skip=\skip171
\sidefootins=\insert248
\sidefootadjust=\skip172
\sidefootheight=\skip173
\sidefoothsep=\skip174
\sidefootvsep=\skip175
\sidefootwidth=\skip176
\m@mdownsf=\skip177
\c@sidefootnote=\count274
\sidefootmarkwidth=\skip178
\sidefootmarksep=\skip179
\sidefootparindent=\skip180
\c@pagenote=\count275
\c@pagenoteshadow=\count276
\mem@pn@lastkern=\skip181
\every@verbatim=\toks20
\afterevery@verbatim=\toks21
\verbatim@line=\toks22
\tab@position=\count277
\verbatim@in@stream=\read2
\verbatimindent=\skip182
\verbatim@out=\write3
\bvboxsep=\skip183
\c@memfbvline=\count278
\c@bvlinectr=\count279
\bvnumlength=\skip184
\fb@frw=\dimen179
\fb@frh=\dimen180
\FrameRule=\dimen181
\FrameSep=\dimen182
\c@cp@cntr=\count280
\c@ism@mctr=\count281
\c@xsm@mctr=\count282
\c@csm@mctr=\count283
\c@ksm@mctr=\count284
\c@xksm@mctr=\count285
\c@cksm@mctr=\count286
\c@msm@mctr=\count287
\c@xmsm@mctr=\count288
\c@cmsm@mctr=\count289
\c@bsm@mctr=\count290
\c@workm@mctr=\count291
\c@sheetsequence=\count292
\c@lastsheet=\count293
\c@lastpage=\count294
(C:\Users\Julian\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/textcase\textcase.sty
Package: textcase 2019/09/14 v1.00 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
)
\c@figure=\count295
\c@lofdepth=\count296
\cftbeforefigureskip=\skip185
\cftfigureindent=\skip186
\cftfigurenumwidth=\skip187
\c@table=\count297
\c@lotdepth=\count298
\cftbeforetableskip=\skip188
\cfttableindent=\skip189
\cfttablenumwidth=\skip190
Package abstract [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package appendix [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package booktabs [2016/05/16] emulated by memoir.
Package ccaption [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package changepage [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package chngcntr [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package chngpage [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package crop emulated by memoir.
Package enumerate [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package epigraph [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package ifmtarg [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package index [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package makeidx [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package moreverb [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package mparhack [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package needspace [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package newfile [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package nextpage [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package pagenote [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package parskip [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package patchcmd [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package setspace [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package shortvrb [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package showidx [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package titleref [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package titling [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package tocbibind [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package tocloft [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package tocvsec2 [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package verbatim [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package verse [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
)
(C:\Users\Julian\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fundus-calligra\callig
ra.sty
Package: calligra 2012/04/10 v1.9 LaTeX package calligra
)
(C:\Users\Julian\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/08/10 v2.0s Standard LaTeX package
)
(C:\Users\Julian\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pd
ftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2020-09-24 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count299
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box52
) (t_problem.aux)
\openout1 = `t_problem.aux'.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `T1/calligra/m/n' will be
(Font) scaled to size 14.40002pt on input line 7.
[1{C:/Users/Julian/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}
] (t_problem.aux) )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
3986 strings out of 480236
55322 string characters out of 2880082
347748 words of memory out of 3000000
20590 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
537702 words of font info for 34 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
48i,10n,55p,162b,226s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:\Users\Julian\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\fonts/pk/ljfour/publi
c/calligra/dpi576\callig15.pk> <C:\Users\Julian\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\fonts/pk/l
jfour/jknappen/ec/dpi600\ecrm1000.pk>
Output written on t_problem.pdf (1 page, 4884 bytes).
PDF statistics:
21 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: The "why" appears to be that the bounding box for the "h" is covering up the "T".  But that doesn't really help you.

Comment: I tried your MWE and the T looked just as it should with no gaps.

Comment: Like Peter, I see no problem in TeX Live; it may be specific to MiKTeX.

Comment: You may want to fully update your MikTeX distribution. For instance, the latest version of the LaTeX format is `<2020-10-01> patch level 2`, whereas you're using `<2020-10-01> patch level 1`. Your TeX distribution is also still featuring an outdated version of the `array` package. Can't tell it that's really the culprit, but it's worth fully updating the TeX system before launching any deeper investigations.

Comment: Working well for me, too. With MiKTeX 20.10. Using TeXworks and TeXstudio 3.0.1. LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 1.

Comment: Maybe it is a viewer problem? Does the issue appear in different pdf viewers (Adobe Reader, SumatraPDF, Foxit Reader, MuPDF, open in a web browser)?

Comment: @Marijn d'oh, you're right! It's a viewer problem with TexMaker! I opened the PDF in Firefox and it looks totally fine. Thank you, I'll put an answer and call this closed.

Comment: Unrelated to the question: `\calligra` is a font _switch_. It doesn't take an argument and will change the font in the rest of the current group. You probably want `\textcalligra`.

Answer (score 3):

Try opening the PDF in another viewer. For some reason, the TexMaker PDF viewer displays with the T having a gap, but when opened in another viewer, for example Firefox's PDF viewer the text will display correctly like so:

[image: T shows correctly in Firefox]